# Powershell script to switch current logged in user?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a Powershell script to create a new Windows user an then log into that new account. I can create the new account like so:

```
New-LocalUser -Name $username -Description 'SomeAccountName' -Password 'SomePassword' -PasswordNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword
```

But I am unsure if I am then able to log into the new account from the same script. Is this possible? And if so, how could I go about doing so?

Comment: you're a bit limited but should be able to get something - [see here](https://www.nextofwindows.com/windows-7-8-quick-tip-how-to-switch-user-from-a-command-line) for the only methods I'm aware of. (also these only work on win7+ - but since `New-LocalUser` is Psv4?+ only that shouldn't be a problem :) )

Comment: Why do you want them to log in? Knowing that will help us with what you are trying to achieve. To create the directory structure? You should be able to run near any application as that user. It _should_ create a skeleton structure if you need to drop files or something. I don't think you can completely replicate the log in process with pure PS.